# music sound quality is bad under heavy cpu load

Tags: sound, music

My music sound quality is bad under heavy cpu load.
Does somebody has the same problem or knows how i can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

#### Icrease priority

We are able to increase the priority of the pulseaudio server (at the cost of other applications) by editing `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` to values like e.g.:

```
high-priority = yes
rlimit-nice = 31      # maximum 31
nice-level = -11      # -11 by default

realtime-scheduling = yes 
rlimit-rtprio = 9     # range from 1 to 99 
realtime-priority = 9 # default  5
```

**Be careful with a priority set too high as this may render your system unresponsive.**

---

#### Change sampling method

It may already be sufficient to change the resampling method of pulseaudio in the `daemon.conf`:

```
resample-method = speex-float-1
```

to a value that consumes less CPU power (e.g. `src-sinc-medium-quality`, or different values for `speex-float`).

Answer (score 0):

This problem is most likely caused by your computer doing too many things at once to release enough cpu time for the decoding of audio from mp3, ogg, flac etc. (although I have seen similar which I diagnosed as a disk caching issue once)

It can happen on a highly specced machine or a netbook - just depends on loading the CPU heavily.

You haven't included any details as to what CPU, memory, type of encoding etc you are using, so specifics are tricky, but:

Your simplest plan - don't load the CPU so much when listening to audio
Alternatively - you could try and [renice the player process](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jaunty/en/man1/renice.1.html) so it gets a bigger slice of the cpu pie